# How can I shorten this LIKE statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

```
+ case when 
(
    (
        PYMT.element like '____.T.T-0_______.____.________' or 
        PYMT.element like '____.T.T-K_______.____.________'
    )
    and len(PYMT.element) = 31
) 
then '' 
else '12|'
end
```

I'm trying to find a more elegant way of doing this `like` statement. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: You have enough reputation to know images of code are less than well received.

Comment: updated.................

Comment: You can remove the `LEN` since you aren't using a leading or trailing wild card. It's redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing I can see you could do instead is to replace both `LIKE`s with a single one:

```
PYMT.element LIKE '____.T.T-[0K]_______.____.________'
```

And, as WEI_DBA mentions, you can remove the `len(PYMT.element) = 31`, as the `LIKE` handles that already.

Comment: so if I do [0K] it means "either 0 or K" ?

Comment: In a `LIKE` `[0K]` means that that space can be the character `'0'` or `'K'`, yes.

Comment: great. thank you. i can accept your answer in 6 mins.